# Trying to implement my own React alike framework, component system

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, implementation, virtual-dom

Most of the time I use Vue.js or React to build my front-end web apps, mostly because I love how their component system work.
So now I am trying to build my own javascript framework like React, this is what I've go so far:

I am using Babel for my javascript, and it is all bundled with webpack. I use [babel-plugin-transform-jsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-jsx) to transform this jsx type expression:

```
var object = (
  <article>
    <h1>Hello, kitten!</h1>
    <img href="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="A cute kitten"/>
    It is soooo cute.
  </article>
)
```

Into this javascript object:

```
var object = {
  elementName: 'article',
  attributes: {},
  children: [
    {
      elementName: 'h1',
      attributes: {},
      children: ['Hello, kitten!']
    },
    {
      elementName: 'img',
      attributes: {
        href: 'http://placekitten.com/200/300',
        alt: 'A cute kitten'
      },
      children: null
    },
    'It is soooo cute.'
  ]
}
```

I know how to build a real DOM with this object, but lets say that I want to include another component inside of the JSX, like so:

```
render() {
   <article>
      <OtherComponent />
   </article>
}
```

And inside of OtherComponent class I would have a render function which would be inserted on its parent, just like React.
How can I do that?

Comment: If you've ever seen how React renders the child elements, you'll see that it basically passed each child as a third argument to the `createElement` function (which in turn calls `createElement` on that component/element). I'm not exactly sure if that helps you or not, though, haha

Comment: Yes but what if the child element is OtherComponent? What I want is if that happens, the render() function of the OtherComponent class must be called and rendered in the proper place